# Function in javascript only working once

Tags: javascript

I am using this function for a button:

```
points1 = 0;
function onclick1 (points1) {
    points1 += 5;
    document.getElementById("point1").innerHTML = points1;
}
```

Right now function only works on the first button click but not on subsequent clicks.
How do I fix it?

Comment: It's better to not use global variables and functions.

Answer (score 4):

You are passing points1 in as a var in the function. Try and change it to -->

```
points1=0;

function onclick1(){
points1+=5;
document.getElementById("point1").innerHTML=points1;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You've declared `points1` as a function parameter, so it hides the global variable of the same name. Remove that parameter and it should work:

```
var points1=0;
function onclick1(){
    points1+=5;
    document.getElementById("point1").innerHTML=points1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
point1 = 0;
function myFunction()
{
point1 += 5;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=point1;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to trigger a function.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```